# ngRoute as tab like in jquery

Tags: jquery, angularjs

I guess I've done it wrong, structurally. I want my sidebar to have as tabs, then within each tab there will be dynamic content.

So far I tried this http://plnkr.co/edit/ETxaZ2ESI9ftCOUSRDcP?p=preview

you try to click tab and ply around with the content, then later you come b everything is reseted. Or shouldn't I use ngroute?

Answer (score 0):

The Problem is that AngularJS deletes a controller assigned to a route after changing it. So actually, you can try two things:

1. Dont use ngRoute, but implement your tabs with `ng-show`
2. Preserve all state-related properties of your controller inside a `viewStateService`. Since services are singletons, they gonna be the same even after changing the route.

Comment: And? You can use a dynamic ng-show. Each of your tabs has an `$index`, so save the current active tab´s index in a scope-variable like `$scope.activeTab`, then you can do `ng-show="activeTab == $index"`.

Comment: The parent controllet is not deleted by AngularJS when child route changed. So this is not the problem when you want to have some data alive.
Today I use ng-route for tabs when my tabs contain grids. Doing so My app loads the grids only when tab with the grid is activated. When you use ngShow you have to implement the logic.